# how should I store objects

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class called `human` that holds information like `int age, int height`, `QString name` etc..

the user clicks on a pushbotton to add new human information and the program creates new human objects as the user enters information (e.g., john, johan, ...).

I want to store all the objects then I would like to be able to access each individual object and its members. what would be best to store objects?

What I was thinking is to do to declare   `static std::vector<human*> humanVector;` on the header file

then

```
humanVector.push_back( new human(name, age, height));
```

does it sound correct or do I need to do with a different way or use a different decleration like
 `static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<human>> humanVector;`

Comment: If it's C++ and it contains `new`, it doesn't "sound correct" :-S (It sounds more like someone following a Java tutorial and saying to themselves, "Now I know C++".)

Comment: I am new in C++:) I was following someone else's tutorial that I could not find now, but I saw different usages as well. I could not decide how I should store the objects. I would appreciate if you could point me the correct way to store it.

Comment: `std::vector<human>` would be a start.

Comment: Is there a specific need for the declaration to be `static`? Also, do you need to store  pointers to `human` objects, why not just store the actual objects, like Kerrek SB suggests (`std::vector<human>`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use static `std::vector<human*> humanVector;` , need to make sure to free the objects in vectors before the scope of vector, otherwise it leads to memory leak problem.

Using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<human>> humanVector;`  is exception-safe, it takes care of distructing the objects. std::shared_ptr is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer. The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens:
the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed. 
the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is assigned another pointer via operator= or reset().